# Tabelview rows not showing(because of wrong constraints) in swift

Tags: swift, constraints, tableview

this is the cell design   [design img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz7Fu.png)

for pic

```
 width = height = 40, top = 15, leading = 15
```

here for name **rose d** i have given constraint

```
  width = 60, top = 15, leading = 10
```

for **place a bid on the request** label

```
  top = 15, leading = 5
```

for **trip for few days** label

```
  top = 15, leading = 5, trailing >= 20
```

for **dummy caption shoe here** label

```
  trailing = 20, leading to image = 10, top to rose d = 5 and label lines = 0
```

for **46 mins ago** label

```
  top and leading to dummy caption.. lable = 10, trailing  >= 20
```

i don't want to give row fixed height.. because dummy caption label may increase..

now rows not showing in tableview.. only if i give fixed height then only showing

here where i go wrong with constraints.. so i not getting rows in tableview, please guide me

**if i give bottom constraint to lowest label and if i add more text to middle label then coming like this** [design and constraint of middle label img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S7YM.png)

Comment: Have you implemented estimatedHeightForRow delegate method?

Comment: @Neeraj, still not coming

Comment: its mandatory to have top-bootom-leading-trailing constraint please make sure you have all constraints

Comment: or share screenshot for constraints

Comment: You should have only 2 labels. One for the "text" include red/pinkish, black and blue text (can be done with NSAttributedString) and one for the ago. I'd set mainLabel top to superview, bottom to timeLabel, timeLabel bottom to superview. Add also mainLabel height >= 15 and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any bottom constraints, therefore the layout doesn't know how to anchor the bottom of the cell to your UI elements.

Set constraints from the lowest element to the bottom of the cell's content view, or more flexibly set greater or equal to constraints from all lower elements so you don't need to worry about the number of lines in your labels.

However, I think a better approach would be to use a single label with an attributed string to provide the colouring.  This will be more flexible and ensure the spacing between words looks natural.

Comment: yes, if i give bottom constraint to lowest label then rows are coming but the middle label ie.. `dummy caption` label text increases then it show error.. for middle label constraints are `leading, trailing, top, bottom = 5`

Comment: i have given label lines to 0

Comment: it would help if you added your actual constraint code to the querstion, rather than the summary, and a copy of the error.

Comment: i have posted constraints in question

Comment: Constraints are fine.  Is the issue it's not wrapping to a second line (hard to see on image!)? Check line break is set to word wrap (not truncate), desired width is auto, intrinsic size is default